# A project which detect block probability on a network using Wavelength Division Multiplexing (WDM) technology and I have stuck with it

Tags: python-3.x, networking, python-multithreading

I'm having a project with the Digital Routing course and you can find the detail from the link below:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EG1p_xNa30Aj756AqC4h2uk3Okj1mPAY

I don't know why I'm having error.
When I use for small network, It run smoothly but when I use for complex network, the error comes.
The error is the result of blocking probability always = 0. Also when I used more ratio, like 10, sometimes the number changed, somes it's not. Moreover when I have the numbers, they were not correct.
And I have stuck with this for a week now.
I just want to find correct blocking probability for the network.

Please help me. I appreciate so much for your help.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import _thread

#Testing

#Creating events:
def event(events,hold):
#Initialize source, destination, arrival time, holding time arrays
source = np.zeros(events,dtype=np.int8)
destination = np.zeros(events, dtype=np.int8)

#Assign source and destination for each lightpath
for i in range(events):
    source[i] = np.random.uniform(1,18)
    destination[i] = np.random.uniform(1,18)
    while(destination[i]==source[i]):
        destination[i] = np.random.uniform(1,18)

# Mean hold time:
hold = hold  # 1/lambda
holding = np.random.exponential(hold, events)

event = np.vstack((source, destination,holding)).T
return event

def arrival(events,arrival):
# Mean interarrval and hold time:
interarrival = arrival  # 1/lambda
arrival = np.random.exponential(interarrival, events)
return arrival


def freePath(event,G):
path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=event[0], target=event[1])
return path

def freeWavelength(path):
wavelength = []
for i in range(len(path) -1 ):
    free = []
    for j in range(8):
        available = G[path[i]][path[i+1]][j+1]['available']
        if (available>0):
            if (j+1) not in free:
                free.append(j+1)
    wavelength.append(free)
freeWavelength = wavelength[0]
for i in range(len(path)-1):
    freeWavelength = set(freeWavelength) & set(wavelength[i])
return np.array(list(freeWavelength))

def checkBlocking(freeWavelength):
if (len(freeWavelength) == 0):
    return False #If blocked
else:
    return True #If NOT blocked

def assignWavelength(freeWavelength):
wavelength = np.random.choice(freeWavelength)
return wavelength

def Transmission(event,wavelength,path,G):
for i in range(len(path)-1):
    nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'available', {(path[i],path[i+1],wavelength): (G[path[i]][path[i+1]][wavelength]['available'] - 1)})
#print G.edges(data=True)
start_time = time.time()
while(True):
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    #print elapsed_time
    if (elapsed_time>=event[2]):
        break
for i in range(len(path) - 1):
    nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'available', {(path[i],path[i+1],wavelength): (G[path[i]][path[i+1]][wavelength]['available'] + 1)})
#print G.edges(data=True)

# def Release(wavelength,path,G):
#     for i in range(len(path) - 1):
#         nx.set_edge_attributes(G, 'available', {(path[i], path[i + 1], wavelength): (G[path[i]][path[i + 1]][wavelength]['available'] + 1)})

G = nx.MultiGraph()

for i in range(17):
G.add_node(i+1)

#Add edges:
for i in range(17):
for j in range(8):
    G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,16), (1,17)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(2,1), (2,17),(2,3)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(3,2), (3,17), (3,10), (3,4)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(4,3), (4,10), (4,7), (4,5)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(5,4), (5,6)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(6,5), (6,7)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(7,4), (7,6),(7,8)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(8,7), (8,9)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(9,10), (9,8)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(10,4),(10,3),(10,9),(10,11), (10,17)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(11,10),(11,12), (11,14)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(12,11), (12,13)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(13,12), (13,14)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(14,11),(14,13),(14,15), (14,17)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(15,14), (15,16)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(16,17), (16,1)],key=j+1, available=8)
    G.add_edges_from([(17,1), (17,2), (17,3), (17,10), (17,14), (17,16)],key=j+1, available=8)
#Checking:
# print "Nodes"
# print G.nodes(data=True)
# print "Edges"
# print G.edges(data=True)

#Draw the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels=True)
plt.show()


def running(event,arrival,multiplier):
blocking = 0

event = event(100,1*multiplier)
print (event)

arrival= arrival(100,0.1)
print (arrival)

i = 0
while(True):
    start_time = time.time()
    while(True):
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        # print elapsed_time
        if (elapsed_time >= arrival[i]):
            break
    current_event = event[i]
    path = freePath(current_event,G)
    print (i+1)
    print (path)
    free_Wavelength = freeWavelength(path)
    if (checkBlocking(free_Wavelength)):
        #print "test"
        wavelength = assignWavelength(free_Wavelength)
        #print wavelength
        _thread.start_new_thread(Transmission,(current_event,wavelength, path, G))
        #Transmission(current_event,wavelength, path, G)
        # except:
        #     print "Error: unable to start thread"
    else:
        blocking +=1
    i+=1
    if (i>(len(event)-1)):
        break
return blocking

blocking = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(5):
blocking[i] = running(event,arrival,i+1)
print (blocking)
blocking = blocking/100
ratio = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]

# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(ratio, blocking, 3)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
ratio_new = np.linspace(ratio[0], ratio[-1], 50)
blocking_new = f(ratio_new)

plt.plot(ratio,blocking,'o', ratio_new, blocking_new)
plt.xlim([ratio[0]-1, ratio[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should explain here what's the error, what you tried already, what you want to achieve...in order for helping other to help you.

Comment: Thank you for guild me. I already edited on my post.